# LWJGL GLFW_FORMAT_UNAVAILABLE error

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Here is my class that supposed to create app (main entry point is `run` method)

```
public class Geom {

    public static class GLContextConfig {
        int windowWidth = 800;
        int windowHeight = 600;
        int majorVersion = 3;
        int minoVersion = 2;
        int fsaaSamples = 0;
        String windowTitle = "GLFW Geom";
        GLContextFlags flags = new GLContextFlags();

        public static class GLContextFlags {
            int fullscreen = 1;
            int vsync = 1;
            int cursor = 1;
            int stereo = 1;
            int debug = 1;
            int all;
        }
    }

    private GLContextConfig glContextConfig = new GLContextConfig();
    private Queue<IRenderable> objectQueue;
    private FloatBuffer clearColorBuffer;
    private GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback;
    private GLFWKeyCallback keyCallback;
    private long window;

    public void run() {
        try {
            prepare();
            mainLoop();
            clear();
        } finally {
            glfwTerminate();
            errorCallback.release();
        }
    }

    public void putObjectToRenderQueue(IRenderable obj) {
        objectQueue.add(obj);
    }

    private void prepare() {
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err));
        if (glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE) {
            throw new CoreException("Failed to initialize GLFW!");
        }
        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, glContextConfig.majorVersion);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, glContextConfig.minoVersion);

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, glContextConfig.fsaaSamples);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_STEREO, glContextConfig.flags.stereo == 1 ? GL_TRUE : GL_FALSE);

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);

        if (glContextConfig.flags.fullscreen == 1) {
            if (glContextConfig.windowWidth == 0 || glContextConfig.windowHeight == 0) {
                glContextConfig.windowWidth = 0;
                glContextConfig.windowHeight = 0;
            }
        }

        window = glfwCreateWindow(glContextConfig.windowWidth, glContextConfig.windowHeight, glContextConfig.windowTitle, NULL, NULL);
        if (NULL == window) {
            throw new CoreException("Failed to create GLFW window!");
        }
        glfwSetWindowTitle(window, glContextConfig.windowTitle);

        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action,
                    int mods) {
                if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
                    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
                }

            }

        });

        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, (vidmode.width() - glContextConfig.windowWidth) / 2, (vidmode.height() - glContextConfig.windowHeight) / 2);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(glContextConfig.flags.vsync);
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    private void mainLoop() {
        GL.createCapabilities();

        while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GLFW_FALSE) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            render();

            glfwSwapBuffers(window);        
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    private void render() {
        double time = glfwGetTime();
        clearColorBuffer = BufferSupportUtils.makeFloatBuffer(
                ArraySupportUtils.addOpacityToColor(
                        new float[] { 
                                (float) (Math.sin(time) * 0.5f + 0.5f), 
                                (float) (Math.cos(time) * 0.5f + 0.5f), 
                                0.0f 
                        }, 
                        1.0f
                )
        );
        GL30.glClearBufferfv(GL11.GL_COLOR, 0, clearColorBuffer);
    }

    private void clear() {
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        keyCallback.release();
    }
}
```

But I get this error

```
[LWJGL] GLFW_FORMAT_UNAVAILABLE error
        Description : WGL: Failed to find a suitable pixel format
        Stacktrace  :
                org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1168)
                org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1251)
                com.chucke.geom.core.Geom.prepare(Geom.java:125)
                com.chucke.geom.core.Geom.run(Geom.java:88)
                com.chucke.geom.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:11)
Exception in thread "main" com.chucke.geom.core.prototype.exception.CoreException: Failed to create GLFW window!
        at com.chucke.geom.core.Geom.prepare(Geom.java:127)
        at com.chucke.geom.core.Geom.run(Geom.java:88)
        at com.chucke.geom.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:11)
```

The error references to that line

```
window = glfwCreateWindow(glContextConfig.windowWidth, glContextConfig.windowHeight, glContextConfig.windowTitle, NULL, NULL);
```

What's the problem?

P.S I use OpenGL Bible + lwjgl with adjustments

Answer (score 0):

[GLFW "WGL: Failed to find a suitable pixel format"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881461/glfw-wgl-failed-to-find-a-suitable-pixel-format)

The issue was with

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_STEREO, glContextConfig.flags.stereo == 1 ? GL_TRUE : GL_FALSE);
```

as I am using integrated `Intel` video.